Is this an example of first conditional?
Is this an example of first conditional?

Can we use your father's vacation house if he's not staying there?

If not so, can someone please explain about this example?
Thanks.
The question was in an English exam about mixed conditionals,but mixed ones are about second and third conditionals.
It was a blank question and the correct option was staying. I need to know whether it is a first conditional talking about possible situation

Can you please [edit] the question and tell us what you already know about conditionals, and why you're unsure whether this example is a conditional? No sense in telling you things you already know.

@gotube Maybe the OP is confused as this is a question sentence?

@user1176409 That'd be great to know too. Also, if there's a context surrounding this sentence, including it would help.

Does this answer your question? Zero conditional sentence with "can"

@gotubeI edited the question

The whole zero/first/second/third/mixed conditional classification scheme has problems; but if we accept that scheme, then yes, this sentence is most likely an example of the "first conditional", though technically it's ambiguous and could also be an example of the "zero conditional".
It's clearly not an example of the "second conditional" or the "third conditional", because the if-clause uses the present tense ("if he's not") rather than the past subjunctive ("if he weren't") or pluperfect subjunctive ("if he hadn't been") or any of the variants of these that are common in speech ("if he wasn't", "if he wouldn't have been", etc.).
The reason it's ambiguous between the first conditional and the zero conditional is that English doesn't fully distinguish present and future tenses — to a large degree there's just a single "non-past" tense — and the verb can is ambiguous between both. (Compare "most birds can fly" with "Can you come over tomorrow?") So there's nothing explicit in your sentence that indicates whether it's asking for a general rule ("Can we use your father's vacation house whenever he's not staying there?") or asking about a specific event when the father might be (or is known to be) absent.
(Note: This is not the same ambiguity that gotube mentions in his/her answer. Despite what (s)he writes, both interpretations that (s)he mentions are conditional constructions, and specifically belong to the first conditional.)

The question was in an English exam about mixed conditionals, […]

It's not uncommon for a test to include a few examples that don't fit the pattern they're primarily testing for, because they want you to engage your brain instead of just following the pattern by rote. They obviously expect you to already be familiar with the first conditional, so even if the exam is about mixed conditionals, it's valid for it to have some examples of the first conditional as well.

[…] but mixed [conditionals] are about second and third conditionals.

I think the right way to think about the term "mixed conditional" is as an acknowledgment that the classification of conditionals as zero/first/second/third doesn't fully work. This is because it tries to conflate a few different dimensions (open vs. irrealis, tense of if-clause, tense of then-clause) and there are just too many possibilities. So if you've reached the point where you're learning about the "mixed conditional", then I think you're best off just forgetting about the whole numbering scheme; it helped you learn to recognize and produce the most common patterns, but now you can move on.

I need to know whether it is a first conditional […]

You don't!

I need to know whether it is […] talking about possible situation

Yes; or at least, the speaker apparently believes that this situation is possible (or even that it's certain, as gotube explains).

It might be a conditional, depending on the intended meaning in the context.
The natural reading of this example is that everybody knows the father isn't staying at the vacation house, and the speaker is simply asking permission. In this case, it's not a conditional, because the "if"-clause gives a reason, not a condition. It could be reworded like this, while keeping the same meaning:

Can we use your father's vacation house since he's not staying there?
Can we use your father's vacation house considering he's not staying there?
Can we use your father's vacation house given that he's not staying there?

On the other hand, if it's unknown whether the father is staying at the vacation house, then the speaker is asking for permission to stay there on the condition that the father is not staying there. In this case, it is a conditional, and can be reworded like this:

Can we use your father's vacation house if it turns out that he's not staying there?

